# Rename a file when clicking at a hyperlink to download a file using WebMatrix

Tags: webmatrix

I'm using [WebMatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_WebMatrix). I uploaded a abc.doc file to a folder. A hyperlink is created to download the file. Example: `<a href="~/uploads/StudyMaterial/abc.doc">`.

When I click on the link, the file will be downloaded with name abc.doc. How can I rename it to Hello.doc when downloading the file?

Comment: You need a file server/handler to send the file to the client and give it a new name.  If you link directly to abc.doc then IIS just sends the file directly, so you don't have an option to rename it.  Can you please give more detail about what you've tried and what you're looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to rename the file you could set the `filename` attribute when adding the `Content-Disposition` header to the response:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Hello.doc\"");
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tagged.
@foreach(var i in materials){
    <li>
        <a href="~/uploads/StudyMaterial/@i.Title">@k.Title</a>
    </li>
}

where should i add the Response.AppendHeader()?

Comment: You will need a Razor page to serve your files. Then you will reference this page: `<a href="~/download.cshtml/@i.Title">@k.Title</a>`. Inside this page you will stream the file to the response and add the Content-Disposition header which will allow you to change its name.

Comment: I tried with 
Response.WriteFile("~/uploads/StudyMaterial/25.docx");
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=hheelo.docx");

When i tried to open the downloaded file, it said the file is corrupted. Is it i use the wrong method?

Comment: This is the correct approach. Try clearing the Response buffer (`Response.Clear()`) before writing the file.

Comment: Only docx file cannot be opened directly. Txt, doc, ppt, pdf are no problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is not already corrupted on the server? Are you able to open it directly from the folder?

Comment: I can open it directly from the folder.

Comment: I added Response.End(); Response.Flush(); Now the problem solved. Thanks.